# Can I ask for help planning my trip or is that too focused

Tags: discussion, scope

uh I'd like to go to Southern California on vacation for a few days. Could I ask for help planning the trip given a set of criteria or will that be closed as too focused?

Answer (score 7):

Your best bet is to ask rather a lot of crisp, focused questions that you can use to plan your trip, each in their own Q that can accumulate A:

- can I get between A and B by public transit?
- how feasible is it to visit A and B in a single day?
- what's the closest hotel to A?
- someone told me there are no good restaurants near A, is this true?
- is there an ideal order to visit A, B, and C on the same trip?

Every time you need a fact in order to make a decision, you can ask a question. And over time you will end up with a plan, and the site will end up with a number of useful questions that other people can use to make their own plans, even though they are going for a different amount of time, have a different budget, and so on.

Here is a way to tell if a question is crisp and focused.

- Are you asking for a list? Not crisp.
- Is the answer a fact (length of time, price, distance, number of things) or an opinion (expensive, heavy, worth it, best)? Facts are crisp, opinions are not.
- Are you asking for an offsite resource like a great website to buy something? Off topic.
- Are you asking one question? Focused. Several questions, like "please list all the X and how much do they all cost and which is the best value?" Not focused, and 2/3 of it is not crisp either.
- is the question useful to someone else later? *What's the cheapest flight between A and B on such a date* is not useful later. *I've found flights between A and B but they're a bit too expensive for me, I'm willing to spend more time if I can save money, are there ways to do that?* is better. For some A and B there may be nearby airports, connecting flights, or other suggestions to make the trip more cheaply.
- are you asking someone to suggest a decision (eg drive vs fly, travel north to south or south to north) or give you the information you need to make a decision.

Comment: thanks kate chat wasnt an option as you know

Comment: @caseyr547 I've expanded on some guidance for you so that you have a chance to continue to ask Southern California questions and get your trip planned

Answer (score 6):

One of the close reasons on the site is the WANTA option (we are not travel agents).  You can [read more about what it consists of and why they're not allowed](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1446/101).

However, if you hop into the chat room, and leave a description of what you're hoping to do, some of us love looking at stuff like that :)